# Подключение библиотек postgresql для расширений

Tags: postgresql

Разбираюсь с основами расширений в postgresql 10.6. Для тестирования написал небольшую утилиту и подключил в cmake libpq. Делаю что-то в этом духе:

```
    text *t = PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(0);
    char *str = text_to_cstring(t);
    PG_RETURN_CSTRING(pstrdup(str));
```

`text_to_cstring` и `cstring_to_text` определены как extern и при попытке компиляции выдает следующие ошибки:

```
main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `text_to_cstring(varlena const*)'
main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `cstring_to_text(char const*)'
```

Тоже самое происходит с `palloc`. При сборке в библиотеку и добавление в postgresql все работает.

Что идет не так? И каким способ лучше всего дебажить подобные вещи?

Comment: Вопрос не в том, что значит эта ошибка, а что нужно линковать помимо libpq? И можно ли вообще так делать?

Comment: Надо прилинковать модуль, экспортирующий эти функции. Откуда вы берете `cstring_to_text`?

Comment: Они определены в /usr/pgsql-10/include/server/utils/builtins.h